# terminal transparency, Imagemagick, and X11 root window problem

Tags: ubuntu, xorg, imagemagick, urxvt

I use Ubuntu Natty, urxvt (with 256 colours), and Imagemagick (display -window root [...]) to set the root window to a picture.  When I use the transparancy (-tr) option on urxvt, I get the Ubuntu X login screen background (The pink/purple one) and not the image that is currently on the root window.  See picture at the bottom.

Note that the same problem exists if I run gnome-terminal and set its transparency.

I suspect that imagemagick is not drawing on the right X11 layer but I (and google) cannot figure out what the right option is.

Could the problem be with either the xorg configuration or with window composition?

[image]

Edit: Added a bounty since either no one is interested or no one knows...

Finally, here is the full command I use in debug mode:

```
$ display -window root -geometry '-0-0' -resize '1920x1080>' -debug X11 /media/MediaVault/Images/Wallpapers//347852_1257250176_large.jpg
2011-08-24T15:47:49+01:00 0:00.070 0.060u 6.6.2 X11 display[8318]: xwindow.c/XMakeStandardColormap/8206/X11
  Standard Colormap:
2011-08-24T15:47:49+01:00 0:00.070 0.060u 6.6.2 X11 display[8318]: xwindow.c/XMakeStandardColormap/8207/X11
    colormap id: 0x20
2011-08-24T15:47:49+01:00 0:00.070 0.060u 6.6.2 X11 display[8318]: xwindow.c/XMakeStandardColormap/8209/X11
    red, green, blue max: 255 255 255
2011-08-24T15:47:49+01:00 0:00.070 0.060u 6.6.2 X11 display[8318]: xwindow.c/XMakeStandardColormap/8212/X11
    red, green, blue mult: 65536 256 1
2011-08-24T15:47:49+01:00 0:00.070 0.060u 6.6.2 X11 display[8318]: xwindow.c/XMakeImage/5588/X11
  XImage:
2011-08-24T15:47:49+01:00 0:00.070 0.060u 6.6.2 X11 display[8318]: xwindow.c/XMakeImage/5589/X11
    width, height: 1200x717
2011-08-24T15:47:49+01:00 0:00.070 0.060u 6.6.2 X11 display[8318]: xwindow.c/XMakeImage/5591/X11
    format: 2
2011-08-24T15:47:49+01:00 0:00.070 0.060u 6.6.2 X11 display[8318]: xwindow.c/XMakeImage/5593/X11
    byte order: 0
2011-08-24T15:47:49+01:00 0:00.070 0.060u 6.6.2 X11 display[8318]: xwindow.c/XMakeImage/5595/X11
    bitmap unit, bit order, pad: 32 0 32
2011-08-24T15:47:49+01:00 0:00.070 0.060u 6.6.2 X11 display[8318]: xwindow.c/XMakeImage/5598/X11
    depth: 24
2011-08-24T15:47:49+01:00 0:00.070 0.060u 6.6.2 X11 display[8318]: xwindow.c/XMakeImage/5600/X11
    bytes per line: 4800
2011-08-24T15:47:49+01:00 0:00.070 0.060u 6.6.2 X11 display[8318]: xwindow.c/XMakeImage/5602/X11
    bits per pixel: 32
2011-08-24T15:47:49+01:00 0:00.070 0.060u 6.6.2 X11 display[8318]: xwindow.c/XMakeImage/5604/X11
    red, green, blue masks: 0xff0000 0xff00 0xff
2011-08-24T15:47:49+01:00 0:00.090 0.070u 6.6.2 X11 display[8318]: xwindow.c/XMakePixmap/7548/X11
  Pixmap:
2011-08-24T15:47:49+01:00 0:00.090 0.070u 6.6.2 X11 display[8318]: xwindow.c/XMakePixmap/7549/X11
    width, height: 1200x717
2011-08-24T15:47:49+01:00 0:00.090 0.070u 6.6.2 X11 display[8318]: display.c/XDisplayBackgroundImage/13735/X11
  Image: /media/MediaVault/Images/Wallpapers//347852_1257250176_large.jpg[0] 1200x717
2011-08-24T15:47:49+01:00 0:00.090 0.070u 6.6.2 X11 display[8318]: display.c/XDisplayBackgroundImage/13741/X11
```

Comment: Clearly this is a hard problem no one knows the answer to...

Answer (score 2):

I use feh to accomplish this and it works on debian and ubuntu with windowmaker and wterm(rxvt base):

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Feh#As_a_desktop_wallpaper_manager

Excerpt:

```
When using GNOME, you must disable Nautilus from controlling the desktop. The easiest way is to run this command: 
$ gconftool-2 --set /apps/nautilus/preferences/show_desktop --type boolean false
```

I'd be curious if that helps, since it sounds like the issue isn't with the background itself in X, but some other silly gnome tool(really, ancient school yet using gnome?! ;)

Comment: Sadly this made no difference.  Could it be that gdm is messing with things?

Answer (score 1):

If you do tail the syslog and grep for X, does it show any potential errors?

```
sudo tail /var/log/syslog | grep X
```

I am not that familiar with Imagemagick, but if I was in the same position I would definitely check out the config files for it and make sure everything is sounds (vars pointed properly, etc).

Try turning on debugging for imagemagick as well ( -debug X11).

http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#debug

Comment: No error messages in either syslog or Xorg.0.log.  I suspect that display (from imagemagick) sets a different root window from what is assumed to be the real root window as seen by urxvt.  If I use feh to set the wallpaper, transparency works fine.  However, I'd rather use display so I can position my wallpaper where I want it and resize images that do not fit within my monitor.

Comment: What occurs when enabling imagemagick debugging?

Comment: Debugging option and full command line dded to question.

Comment: before you used Imagemagick to overlay the background image on your desktop, was the default background the same as the one shown in the screenshot?  I believe Imagemagick layers your specified image on top of the existing background, which is why the transparency is acting this way.  I'm doing some more digging, I think there may be a way to set gnome to only use the input from Imagemagick as the root window background (without overlay).

Comment: Yes, it is the pink ubuntu one.  BTW, I use fvwm2 and not gnome.  I am ancient school.

Comment: You can set the root window image using the [fvwm-root](http://www.fvwm.org/documentation/manpages/stable/fvwm-root.php) command.  Not sure if you can pipe the output of Imagemagick to this though.

Comment: I also found a good [guide](http://zensites.net/fvwm/guide/), there is an advanced topic that pulls converted images from Imagemagick for icons, it could very well be adapted to suit your purpose.

Comment: Yes, I could do that but I would have to convert to png, and still could not place the images where I wanted it (lower right corner of display).