# Linux wallpaper change

Tags: linux, images, xorg, imagemagick

I am looking for a tool that can resize images and display them on the root window of an X11 display at *a specific coordinates*.   I can use display from iagemagick like so

```
display -window root -geometry '-0-0' -resize '1920x1080>' IMG.png
```

But cannot use it since it does not display on the right root window -- pseudo transparency in urxvt shows the wrong image as shown [here](https://superuser.com/questions/324718/terminal-transparency-imagemagick-and-x11-root-window-problem).  Ideally, I would like to *resize any image bigger than my display*.

Does anyone know of a too that can do the following:

1. Resize the image if it is bigger than some size (aka the display size).
2. Set the images top appear at specific screen coordinates.

**Alternatively** can anyone suggest why display is not working in conjuncture with urxvt -- chances are no one can do that since the previous question was not answered.

Comment: Type `gimp IMG.png`. Then edit the image to how you want it to display and hit `Ctrl-S`. Then use `xsetroot`. Any more effort and you're over-thinking it / yak shaving.

Comment: @amphetamachine: If I only had one images, that would be indeed a good solution. However, I have many images that get changed once every X minutes so I need a command line that can do it.  Thus converting an image with "convert" and displaying it will not do either.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [xsetroot](http://www.xfree86.org/current/xsetroot.1.html)

> The xsetroot program allows you to tailor the appearance of the
>   background ("root") window on a workstation display running X

Comment: -1 It neither allows for a maximum picture size nor allows for specific placement on the display.

Comment: +1 @OP: Don't be so harsh or people won't answer your question (I'm not). As it stands, it's *your* setup that's messed up; this answer would have normally solved it.

Comment: Fair enough.  However, I did not ask what tool can display an image on the root window, I asked for a specific tool that could do two things.  One of those was added as my question was unclear.  Xsetoort, feh, habak, and qiv all can display things but not in the way I want. Hence I feel that the answer is wrong.  Thus the down vote. I have nothing against mOskitO at all and if he can show me how to use xsetroot to get what I want, I will upvote and approve. Ditto if anyone can solve my "messed up setup" -- which nobody could even with bounty bribe.